# Excel look for a string in a text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently working in Excel, I have a column with a string like the following one (Column **D**)

```
POSTE \EUROPA 7-F\CAIOCAIO\ 20012     ITAITA
```

Than I have in another column a list with several values (Column **L**)

```
20000
20012
10032
50021
```

My goal is to add in another column a function that will show as result either TRUE or FALSE, at the moment without success.

I'm gonna show you what I tried until now.

**Match**

```
=MATCH(D2,L3:L5,0)
```

This one doesn't look to work fine with long texts

**Search**

```
=SEARCH($L$3:$L$5,D2)
```

This one looks like doesn't work with lists, if I write directly in the function 20012 it does work

**Vlookup**

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,$L$3:$L$5,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Found this solution online, but didn't understand how it is suppesed to work.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$3:$L$5,D2))))>0
```

the SUMPRODUCT will keep track of the true/false returned by the ISNUMBER as the Search iterated through the range.

Or you can array enter:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$3:$L$5,D2)))
```

This requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If any of the iterations of the SEARCH returns TRUE, the OR will return TRUE.

Comment: This solved, thank you!